# Associating device node with physical disk manually

Tags: linux, udev, device-node

*I am new to the Linux architecture, i was wondering how one can create a device file like sdb or sda and associate it with a physical disk in absence of udev, if it is possible. I have created a hard disk in VBOX now I am building a Linux system from scratch which has very minimal features and doesn't have udev. So is it possible to create device file in the minimal Linux and associate the VBOX hard disk to the device file.*

Comment: Check `MAKEDEV`: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/hwutils.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used devtmpfs for /dev and it worked automatically without udev.